# What is the conventional way to hard-code values in a database?

Tags: database, sqlite, schema, conventions

My application has a database table that is used to record the attendance of employees. And the column `attedance_status` has only three possible values - `"present"`, `"absent"`, `"on_leave"`, and `NULL` as default.

How do I add it to the database? So far I have come up with two possible ways.

1. Create another table `attendance_status` with `status_id` and `status_value` and add the above values to it. And then use the id in the application for all SQL queries.
2. Probably the bad way. Hardcode the values (maybe in a config file) and use it throughout the app's SQL queries.

Am I missing the right way? How should this be approached?

Comment: Follow the 1st way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will work, but Option 1 will give you flexibility in the event that the requirements change and is the standard data model.  I would, however, name my columns a little differently.  I would have `id`, `value`, `name`.  Then the references become `attendance_status.id` and `attendance_status.value`.  The third column is available for use in displays or reports or whatever. `value` is `on_leave` and `name` is `On leave`.

Option 2 works provided the data input point is totally closed.  If someone codes new functionality there is the risk that he or she will invent something different to mean the same thing like `onLeave`.